# Subset dataframe based on the slope

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['fruit'] = ['apple','pear','banana','banana','pear','banana','apple','apple','pear','apple','apple','apple']
df['price'] = [2,1,3,3,1,3.3,1.8,1.8,1,1.6,1.6,1.6]
df['date_buy'] = ['01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005']
df.date_buy = df.date_buy.astype('datetime64')
df.set_index('date_buy', inplace = True)
```

The data is:

```
            fruit   price
date_buy        
2005-01-01  apple   2.0
2005-01-01  pear    1.0
2005-01-01  banana  3.0
2005-01-01  banana  3.0
2005-01-02  pear    1.0
2005-01-02  banana  3.3
2005-01-02  apple   1.8
2005-01-02  apple   1.8
2005-01-03  pear    1.0
2005-01-03  apple   1.6
2005-01-03  apple   1.6
2005-01-03  apple   1.6
```

I have converted this dataframe into a pivot table:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['date_buy'],columns = ['fruit'], values = ['fruit'], aggfunc = len).\
fillna(0).resample('D', level=0).sum()


            price
fruit       apple   banana  pear
date_buy            
2005-01-01  1.0     2.0     1.0
2005-01-02  2.0     1.0     1.0
2005-01-03  3.0     0.0     1.0
```

I want to subset this dataset based on a criteria: top two slopes of the trend line. For apple the slope is 1, for banana is -1 and for pear the slope is 0. The result should be:

```
            price
fruit       apple   pear
date_buy            
2005-01-01  1.0     1.0
2005-01-02  2.0     1.0
2005-01-03  3.0     1.0
```

This dataset is just a concept from a much larger dataset, that's why I'm not subsetting by just the names of the two fruits I see. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) from numpy to get the slopes. While not necessary, you can use a delta on the index in terms of days as x and y as the full pivoted dataframe. Then use `argsort` and select the number of top slopes you want. Finally, use `iloc` to get the columns

```
pv_df = (df.pivot_table(index=['date_buy'],columns = ['fruit'], 
                        values = ['fruit'], aggfunc = len)
           .fillna(0).resample('D', level=0).sum()
        )
# number of top slopes
nb_top = 2
# get the slopes
slopes = np.polyfit(x=(pv_df.index - pv_df.index.min()).days, 
                    y=pv_df, deg=1)[0]
#select the columns
res = pv_df.iloc[:, np.argsort(slopes)[-nb_top:]]
print(res)
           price      
fruit       pear apple
date_buy              
2005-01-01   1.0   1.0
2005-01-02   1.0   2.0
2005-01-03   1.0   3.0
```

Note: for the slopes, you can use directly `slopes = np.polyfit(x=pv_df.index.astype(int), y=pv_df, deg=1)[0]` but the values are less obvious compared to 1,0 and -1 you said in your question

Comment: the trick of subtracting the min date was a clever move @Ben.T, thank you very much!